# Cannot set Web Service constructor parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, constructor, unity-container

**Question Back ground:**

I have a project consisting of a DLL, a web service and a test project. Currently I'm simply trying to set the web service constructor string parameter through the use of Unity.

**The issue & error:**

The following shows the constructor structure of the web service class 'VersionControlFacade':

```
 private string _url;

 public VersionControlService()
 {
 }

 public VersionControlService(string url)
 {
    _url = url;
 }
```

If I simply pass the 'url' parameter as shown in the following code it is fine:

```
 var newVersionControlFacade = new VersionControlFacade(@"http://somelink.com");
```

When I try and pass it using my Unity IoC container as shown:

```
 var container = new UnityContainer();
 container.RegisterType<IVersionControlFacade, ProxyHandler>();
 container.RegisterType<Proxy>();
 container.RegisterType<VersionControlService>(new InjectionConstructor(@"http://somelink.com"));
 return container.Resolve<IVersionControlFacade>();
```

The following error is being throw stating that the web service does not contain a constructor that takes a string parameter even though it clearly does.:

Result Message:

**Test method Test_Unity threw exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The type   VersionControl.WebService.VersionControlService does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (String).**

Can anyone steer me in the right direction here? Do I need to re-add the web reference for it to see this new constructor?

Comment: Try reading the web reference,  Also to debug try to call the class directly,  at least you will see if the constructor is being seen.

Comment: Here is a sample with injection constructor and it works fine for me - http://dotnetfiddle.net/Vb1uEK

Comment: @LawrenceThurman Not sure I understand by 'reading the web reference could you elaborate please. I have called the class directly and it works, it just seems to be trying to set it through Unity.

Comment: @SergeyLitvinov Thanks for your example. I have used unity the way you have shown and the way I have shown many times, but I've never attempted to set a web service constructor using Unity and this is where the issue is coming in.

Comment: sorry - re-add the web service.