# Error resolving c# Unity constructor

Tags: c#, interface, constructor, unity-container

**Question Background:**

I am currently configuring a Unity container and am having issues setting the constructor of a class.

The class in question's constructor is set as shown. It takes in 3 string parameters and then 2 objects that I am setting up in the container.

```
public VersionControlFacade(string serverPath, string username, string password, IConnectionManager connectionManager, IPromoManager promoManager)
```

The configured Unity container for the above class is as shown:

```
container.RegisterType<IPromoManager, promotionManager>();
container.RegisterType<IConnectionManager, connectionManager>();
container.RegisterType<ITfsVersionControlFacade, TfsVersionControlFacade>(new InjectionConstructor(connectionString, username, password));
```

**The Error:**

Currently when trying to resolve the `UnityContainer` object, the following exception is being thrown:

> The type VersionControlFacade does not have a constructor that takes the parameters (String, String, String)

I understand this, I am indeed passing in two other parameters, but it was my belief that as I have registered `IPromoManager` and `IConnectionManager` that these would be resolved and automatically injected into the `VersionControlFacade` constructor?

Can anyone tell me where the logic is wrong here, and what I can do to resolve it?

Comment: Your other question (very similar to this one) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675845/cannot-set-web-service-constructor-parameter shows that maybe you have a naming problem? You implement `VersionControlService` even though the constructor you're interested in is `VersionControlFacade`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
container.RegisterType<ITfsVersionControlFacade, TfsVersionControlFacade>(new InjectionConstructor(connectionString, username, password, typeof(IConnectionManager), typeof(IPromoManager)));
```

See

[Unity InjectionConstructor for multiparam constructor overriding only single one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866643/unity-injectionconstructor-for-multiparam-constructor-overriding-only-single-one)